# What is the difference between "I run" and "I do run"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Sometimes I read sentences like "I do run...", "I do love.." or "I do write..". What is the difference to "I run..", "I love..." or "I write..."?

Is the using of "do" in this cases a way to make the verb more important, like "I DO(!) love"?

Comment: Does anyone else have an [_"I met her in the morning and my heart stood still"_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pp_vRjCVue4) earworm now? (After all, there's a precedent for using that song with [English learners](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJqlfMP-klM)... ;^)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/difference-between-did-verb-and-just-verbed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'I do run, 'I do write' etc. add emphasis to the expression, for e.g.

saying

> I run in the morning. (normal activity)

while saying

> I do run in the morning.

It could be like this,

Person 1: I have never seen you run in the morning. Do you ever run?

Person 2: Yes **I do run** in the morning, it is just that I run in some other region/ park.